# Do Smartphones have nearby notifications turned on automatically?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, proximity, eddystone

Do people manually have to turn on nearby notifications to receive proximity marketing messages?

And with android factory default settings, is nearby notifications settings on or off?

Thanks for your help. It's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Most Android phones outside of China will have Google Nearby enabled by default and location and bluetooth turned on by default.  This is true because Google requires it be installed with default settings for the Google Play Store to be pre-installed on new Android devices.

However, this doesn't mean it will always work because there are lots of exceptions:

- Any Android device that does not have Google apps installed by default (Gmail, Maps, etc.) do not have Google Play Service and will not show Nearby notifications.  Amazon Fire OS tablets (and the Fire phone) are examples of this.   These will never show Nearby notifications.
- Android devices sold in mainland China do not have Google apps or Google Play Services installed.  These will never show Nearby notifications.
- Older Android devices that do not have automatic app updates turned on, and do not have Google Play Services 7.8.0+ (released in July 2015) will not get Nearby notifications, because that minimum Google Play Services app version is needed to display them.
- Any device without Bluetooth LE support (or with Android 4.2.x or earlier which does not support Bluetooth LE) will not show Google Nearby messages, because Bluetooth LE  is needed for it to work.
- If a user proactively turns off bluetooth (common) or location services (also common) even if the user leaves Nearby enabled, notifications will not be received, as bluetooth and location are required for it to work.
- The first few times a user sees a Nearby notification, the user is presented with an option to turn it off.  It is very common that users do this even if they don't remember later that they did so.

Because every one of the above cases will break Nearby from working, it's hard to say the percentage of Android phones in any given location that will be able to receive notifications.  In China, the percentage will be very low.  In other parts of the world, it will be a big percentage, but nowhere near 100 percent.  Getting a better estimate of the percentage is difficult, as Google does not publish numbers, and it will certainly vary significantly by the target audience.